# issue with yql (yahoo api's) using oauth

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yql, oauth-ruby

i am using oauth_util.rb ( https://gist.github.com/383159 ) and my YQL query is 
  "select * from search.termextract where context=\"#{text}\""

This works where text is a short string, but fails for the longer ones with the following error:

RuntimeError (Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com" for text [ Virdhawal Khade Wins Historic Medal | Sports News Bangalore November 16, 2010 -19-year-old Indian swimmer and GoSports Foundation awardee, Virdhawal Khade, has made history at the Guangzhou Games by clinching the Bronze Medal in the Men's 50m Butterfly event. ... Starting the Finals in fifth place, Veer's performance was nothing short of astonishing, as he finished with his season best time of 24.31 seconds. He finished 0.65 seconds shy of first placed 27-year-old Zhou Jiawei, the top ranked Chinese Swimmer who is also ... ]):

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

got it... needed to use URI.encode to encode the URI instead of CGI::escape

Comment: actually... the special characters in the text was the real problem. Yahooapi, it seems doesn't handle non-alphanumeric characters properly.